# $http.post gives 404 error via angular;

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest, nodemailer

http://52.11.14.57:9000/#/

Contact form is supposed to send an email but instead console.log shows 404 errors although the data is visible. Node.Js/Express and Angular: however I'm using UI-router with angular....could that cause a conflich?

Angular. app.js

```
app.controller("emailForm", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.user = {test: 1};

$scope.processForm = function(user) {

    console.log('Im in the controller');
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : '/send',
      data    : $scope.user,
      dataType : "json",
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    });
}
 }]);
```

Express app.js:

```
app.post('/send',function(req,res){
 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'aeoneon@gmail.com',
        pass: '*****'
    }
});

var emailBody = '<div>Name: ' + req.user.name + '</div>' +
'<div>Email: ' + req.user.email + '</div>' +
'<div>Phone: ' + req.user.phone + '</div>' +
'<div>Message: ' + req.user.message + '</div>' +
'<div>Date: ' + (new Date()).toString() + '</div>'; 

var mailOptions = { 
    From: 'aeoneon@gmail.com',
    To: 'will@bluenightphoto.com',
    subject: 'Contact from website',
    html: 'emailBody'
};

console.log(mailOptions);
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info){
  if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }else{
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
});
});
});
```

Form:

```
            <form ng-controller="emailForm"  ng-submit='processForm(user)' >
       Name: <br><input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br><br>
E-mail: <br><input type="email" ng-model="user.email" /><br><br>
Phone:<br> <input type="tel" ng-model="user.phone" /><br><br>
Message: <br><textarea rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="user.message"> </textarea><br><br>
    {{user.phone}}

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="my_form.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you plz share the exact 404 error that you see in console.

Comment: On what port express js is listening? Are there is no groups in which you include send? Are you restarted server after adding /send route.

Comment: Is the gmail user and password in your code a fake one, right? ;) If not, can I suggest you to change it asap?

Comment: 404 is a very clear error.. The route is not defined correctly.. What version of express are you running, What is the output from the console ?

Comment: Express with grunt running tasks beforehand. Could live reload be interfering? Have restarted server a few times. Might be down, I should enable nohup in a few hours.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your 'app.post('/send',function(req,res)' function doesn't accept JSON.

if you send x-www-form-urlencoded values it works.

```
$http({
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : '/send',
  data    : 'test=' + $scope.user.test + '&' + 'email=' + $scope.user.email + '&' + 'name=' + $scope.user.name + '&' + 'message=' + $scope.user.message

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simply....

```
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Express doesn't default to html5 if you don't set anything. I removed most of these since I was using angular to handle all my routing and didn't think I needed it.

Make sure you at least have the view engine and a directory set if you store any relevant templates (like emails). Obviously express will not be talking much to your angular router.

Answer (score -2):

url needs to be full path:

```
$scope.processForm = function(user) {

    console.log('Im in the controller');
    $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'http://52.11.14.57:9000/send',
      data    : $scope.user,
      dataType : "json",
      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    });
}
```

if you are testing locally url would be --> `http://localhost:PORT/send`